# How to get shell TAB-completion to work when I redirect grep ag ack output to vim?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, ag

I define `ag` as bash function, to make usage relatively transparent

```sh
ag() { [ $# -gt 0 ] && vim -c silent\ SyntasticToggleMode -c copen -q <(/usr/bin/ag --silent --vimgrep --nogroup "$@") || /usr/bin/ag; }
```

This works fine, but if I try to TAB-complete filename, `vim` gets executed immediately and it gets stuck with

```
$ [git:master] ag sense<TAB>
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
```

Only way out is to kill stuck vim process from another shell.

What's going wrong here and how can this bash function be upgraded (or find some alternative) to make it TAB-completion compatible ?

EDIT `ag` doesn't ship any upstream completion

```
$ [git:master] complete -p ag
-bash: complete: ag: no completion specification
```

Comment: This is most likely not related to Vim, but to how your bash shell is programmed to complete the `ag` command... Can you check the output of `complete -p ag` and [edit] your question to include it?

Comment: PS instead of hardcoding the path to ag you can use `command ag`, and `T && X || Y` is not the same as an if-then-else (consider what happens when T succeeds but X fails). But agreed with filbranden: if the completer tries to run ag to get completion candidates, that’s going to cause problems

Comment: Thanks for tips. `ag: no completion specification` is current state. Will update to `command` itmw here.

Comment: In any case, this is about shell completion and not really about Vim... Vim is only getting involved here because you're using it in your function and the function seems to be called during completion. I'm leaning towards migrating this question to [unix.se] where they'll know more about shell completion.